# Parallel asynchronous Ajax calls from the client

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have 20 data packet in the client and I am pushing one by one to the server via Ajax post. Each call take approximately one minute to yield the response. Is there any way to make few of these requests run parallel.

I have used Jquery promise. However, still the request waiting for the prior one to get completed.

```
var dataPackets=[{"Data1"},{"Data2"},{"Data3"},{"Data4"},{"Data5"}, 
                 {"Data6"},{"Data7"},{"Data8"},{"Data9"},{"Data10"},
                 {"Data11"},{"Data12"},{"Data13"},{"Data14"},{"Data15"},{"Data16"}, 
                 {"Data17"},{"Data18"},{"Data19"},{"Data20"}];

$(dataPackets).each(function(indx, request) {

  var req = JSON.stringify(request);

  setTimeout({

    $.Ajax({
      url: "sample/sampleaction",
      data: req,
      success: function(data) {
        UpdateSuccessResponse(data);
      }

    });
  }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The when...done construct in jQuery runs ops in parallel..

```
$.when(request1(), request2(), request3(),...)
  .done(function(data1, data2, data3) {});
```

Here's an example:
http://flummox-engineering.blogspot.com/2015/12/making-your-jquery-ajax-calls-parallel.html

Comment: Thanks Charles.. i will try this approach. But i will be having 1..n data packets every time. N will be changing depends on some logic. Is there any way i can pass array of function reference in the when block??

Comment: Hi Charles, I have tried this approach. It dint work for me.

Comment: Charles, any other approach?

Comment: One I could think of is response compression.  I'm not sure what web technology you're using on the server side.  For example, here is some documentation for ASP.NET Core, which asserts "Network bandwidth is a limited resource. Reducing the size of the response usually increases the responsiveness of an app, often dramatically. One way to reduce payload sizes is to compress an app's responses.".  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/response-compression?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Comment: Back to your earlier question, yes, you CAN pass an array of function references into the when block.  Let me find a prior code example.

Answer (score 0):

**$.when.apply($, functionArray)** allows you to place an array of functions that can be run in parallel.  This function array can be dynamically created.  In fact, I'm doing this to export a web page to PDF based on items checked in a radio button list.

Here I create an empty array, var functionArray = []; then based on selected items I push a function on to the array  f = createPDF(checkedItems[i].value)

```
$(document).ready(function () {           
    });
    function sleep(milliseconds) {
       var start = new Date().getTime();
       for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
           if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
               break;
           }
       }
    }
    function exportPDFCollection() {
        var f = null;
        var x = 0;
        var checkedItems = $("input:checked");
        var count = checkedItems.length;

        var reportList = $(checkedItems).map(
             function () { 
                 return $(this).next("label").text();
             })
            .get().join(",");

        var functionArray = [];
        var pdf = null;
        for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {              
            f = createPDF(checkedItems[i].value)   
                    .done(function () {
                        pdf = checkedItems[x++].value;
                        alert('PDF =>  ' + pdf + ' created.');                            
                    })
                    .fail(function (jqxhr, errorText, errorThrown) {
                        alert('ajax call failed');
                    });
            functionArray.push(f);
        }
        $.when.apply($, functionArray)
        .done(function () {
            $.get("http://yourserver/ExportPage.aspx",{reports: reportList})
                .done(function () {                    
                       alert('PDF merge complete.');
                 })
                 .fail(function (jqxhr, errorText, errorThrown) {
                        alert('PDF merge failed.  Please try again.');
                 });                
            return true;
        });
    }        
    function createPDF(webPage) {
        return $.get(webPage);                
    }
```